# Characterization of computationally universal functions

Tags: computability, undecidability, semi-decidability, primitive-recursion

Is it correct to state that $u$ is a [universal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_theorem) if and only if

$$
\forall f : \text{RE} \quad
\exists g : \text{R} \quad
\exists h : \text{R} \quad
f = h \circ u \circ g
$$

where RE is the set of [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) functions and R is the set of [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_set) functions? (Should R be replaced with something like [PR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PR_(complexity))?) If so, does anyone know of a reference that states universality in this generic form?

#### Defining "universal function"

I suppose we could define "universal function" itself as follows: Let $\phi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N}$ be an enumeration of all partial computable functions $\mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N}$. Let $\psi : \mathbb{N} \rightharpoonup \mathbb{N}$ where

$$
\psi(n) = \phi(\pi_1(n))(\pi_2(n))
$$

where $\pi_1, \pi_2 : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ are the first and second [Cantor *un*pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). Then $u : A \rightarrow B$ is universal if and only if

$$
\exists g : R \cap (\mathbb{N} \rightarrow A) \quad
\exists h : R \cap (B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}) \quad
\psi = h \circ u \circ g
$$

This resembles a definition of computable functions given in page 24 of Cutland's [*Computability: An Introduction to Recursive Function Theory*](https://www.cambridge.org/ca/academic/subjects/computer-science/programming-languages-and-applied-logic/computability-introduction-recursive-function-theory).

#### Addendum

In a sense, I'm looking for a definition of universality that is more "axiomatic", "abstract", and "generic" than the definition that is usually given, which pertains to partial functions **from naturals to naturals** specifically. My candidate definition requires only that RE be defined/understood over the relevant domain. (From that, co-RE and therefore R fall out automatically.)

To give an example of what I mean from a different area of mathematics, the reals can be *constructed* as Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts of rationals. However, they can also be *directly axiomatized* as the (unique) Dedekind-complete ordered field.

I can try to bootstrap the definition of universality from the naturals-to-naturals case, but doing so requires more artificial machinery and is less elegant. I'm wondering whether there's a more "direct" approach. That's why I'm asking for references that discuss how universality is defined in more general domains (than naturals-to-naturals) directly.

Notions like the [effective topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+topos) and [realizability](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/realizability) might be relevant.

Comment: What is your definition of *universal function*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Added.

Comment: So you're asking whether these two definitions are equivalent? Have you tried proving that they are?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus See the addendum for the motivation.

Comment: The universal function $u$ is supposed to take *two* arguments, at least according to the definition you linked to. But the one in your question takes a single argument. This should be sorted out.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Right. $\psi$ is a one-argument version of a naturals-to-naturals universal function, because it unpairs a single natural into two arguments for a "traditional" two-argument naturals-to-naturals universal function $\phi$. The pairing/unpairing itself is, of course, PR. In other words, pairs of naturals can be encoded as single naturals, and the encoding and decoding is "easy".

Comment: Definition 3.1 of **Turing categories** in this [paper](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/phofstra/T1.pdf) by Hofstra & Cockett gives a general characterization of a universal map (without the pairing-unpairing trickery).

Answer (score 1):

Several authors have considered this question. If you look at some recent work, it will cite older work. The most recent I am aware of is Pieter Hofstra's and Robin Cockett's work on *Turing categories*, see Definition 3.1 in their [Introduction to Turing categories](https://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/phofstra/T1.pdf).